# RecyclerView + Expandable Cardview + TextWatcher how to get it to work?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandablelistview, android-cardview

I have created an expandable listview, where children are a bunch of textviews that the user can change. Upon changing the values of the textviews, the app should save the changed content into DB. It all works perfectly fine with expandableListView and BaseExpandableListAdapter and TextWatcher. 
In order to get the TextWatcher to work, I had no choice but to abandon the viewholder concept.

Now I want to enhance the app to use RecyclerView and Cards to do the same thing. ViewHolder seems to be a must with RecyclerView and I have tried putting TextWatcher inside onCreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolder and the ViewHolder but they all result in mixed up values inside cards.
If I change a value in Card 1, EditText1 and expand Card 2, the same value is in card 2 EditText1,...if I expand Card 3, same value in EditText1...

Can anybody help point me to a tutorial or a working code that implements expandable cards in RecyclerView with TextWatcher?

Thank you